# Flux blocking Netty start-up

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have a `@Repository` reading from a real-time data source. I am making the data available using `Flux.create() { sink->sink.next() }`

A `@Service` is doing the following;

```
@Autowired MyRepository myRepository;

@PostConstruct() public void startUp() {
  ConnectableFlux<Object> cf = myRepository.flux.publish();
  cf.subscribe(System.out::println);
  cf.connect();
}
```

That works and prints the data, but I do **not** get "Netty started" in the logs and `@Controllers` do not respond. If I omit `cf.connect()`, Netty starts. So I assume that `cf.connect()` is blocking Netty.

Ideally, I want the subscription to auto-start. Is using `connect()` in `@PostConstuct` too early? Should I listen for a "Netty Started" event, then `connect(),` or is my subscription just plain wrong?

Edit: If `connect` is run within a deamon `Thread`, Netty does start and the subscription works.

Comment: Removing `@PostConstruct` and using `SmartInitializingSingleton` to call `startUp` doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Putting `@EnableAsync` on the Spring Boot's main Application class and `@Async` on the method above seemed to work.

**Edit:**
I found a better solution here [Connectable Flux blocks on toIterator.forEach, while Flux does not. #1549](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/issues/1549). So my code now looks like this;

```
Flux<MyClass> flux = Flux.create(
   sink -> {
       while(condition) {
          sink.next(nextValueFromDataSource);
       }
       sink.complete();
    }
)
.publish()
.autoConnect(1);
```

Also because of `autoConnect(1)`, there is no need for `@Async`.